# LaTeX large curly brackets

Tags: latex

I would like to have large curly brackets wrap the following contents in a way that the curly brackets spread over multiple lines:

```
('ts', R, 'avk'), ('avk', W, 'r'), ('r', S, 'tp'), ('tp', SE, 'tp'), ('tp', EXP, 'i'), ('i', L, 'i'), ('i', C, 'i'), ('i', PS, 'p'), ('p', DE, 'i'), ('i', D, 'nzi'), ('i', P, 'fh'), ('fh', D, 'nzi'),  ('nzi', PE, 'ra'), ('ra', EXC, 'ra'), ('ra', CA, 'nzp'), ('nzp', L, 'i'), ('i', $\epsilon$, 'anp'), ('anp', TM, 'g'), ('anp', O, 'g'), ('anp', DC, 'ti'), ('ti', E, 'g'), ('g', O, 'g'), ('g', $\epsilon$, 'i'), ('i', $\epsilon$, 'g')
```

Like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I tried to use `\Bigg\{ ... \Bigg\}` but it didnt go over multiple lines

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240868/how-to-write-cases-with-latex . In short, you need the `cases` environment

Comment: @ev-br: Does the [cases environment](https://latex-programming.fandom.com/wiki/Cases_(LaTeX_environment)) add left and right brackets as requested in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You may insert large curly brackets to wrap the following contents in a way that the curly brackets spread over multiple lines with the below code in latex.

```
\delta = \begin{Bmatrix} ('Selected, R,'Ready'),('Ready',S,'Infected',C,'Infected'), \\
 ('Infected',L,'Infected'),('Infected',P,'Zone'),('Infected',D,'Intelligence'), \\('Zone',D,'Intelligence'),('Intelligence',L,'Infected'),'Infected',E,'Goal'), \\ ('Infected',O,'Goal'),('Goal',O,'Goal'),'Goal',L,'Infected') \end{Bmatrix}
```

[Large curly brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R4up.png)

If you only want a left curly bracket you can use the following code instead.

```
    \delta = \begin{cases}
 ('Selected, R,'Ready'),('Ready',S,'Infected',C,'Infected'), \\
 ('Infected',L,'Infected'),('Infected',P,'Zone'),('Infected',D,'Intelligence'), \\('Zone',D,'Intelligence'),('Intelligence',L,'Infected'),'Infected',E,'Goal'), \\ ('Infected',O,'Goal'),('Goal',O,'Goal'),'Goal',L,'Infected')
\end{cases}
```

[Left large curly brackets only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUMNX.png)